# Ubuntu iso for dell precision 5530

Tags: dell

I need some help installing Ubuntu on dell precision 5530.
if there are any tips on changing BIOS settings or Boot.

And if it is better to have dual-boot with Windows? or having one operating system is better?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not change your BIOS  or Boot settings without having a particular purpose /objective.  Better is in the 'eye of the beholder'.  If you are new, I suggest keeping it simple.  When you have a little more experience go for the dual-boot.

That being said I expect this question to be closed by the community because it does not demonstrate due diligence and the second question is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Having a dual-boot or only one OS is entirely up to you. It depends on your specific needs.

There's no special ISO for Dell laptops (or any other brand). Try and/or install using the regular ISO you can download from Ubuntu.com and if there's some hardware that needs additional support (drivers) and you're unable to make it work correctly, just ask a new, specific, question. Make sure to include brand/model and the part in question.

Comment: You can download here https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop then burn the .iso file on a usb, sd card, cd, dvd with etcher https://www.balena.io/etcher/